# Applying conservation of energy to dimensionless form of heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, dimensional-analysis

This is part of a large exercise about dimensional analysis. Basically we have the 1-D heat equation in a rod with infinite length:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \kappa \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}.$$
As an initial profile
we take a distribution which is everywhere vanishing except for a peak in the origin:
$$u(x,0) = u_0\delta(x),$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the delta function.

I have already used dimensional analysis and found two dimensionless quantities:
$$q_1 = \frac{x^2}{\kappa t}, \hspace{0.5cm} q_2 = u \frac{\sqrt{\kappa t}}{u_0}.$$
In view of the expected behavior of the system we may write
$$q_2 = f^*(q_1)$$
for some function $f^*(q_1)$. Using this I have rewritten the heat equation in terms of $q_1,q_2$ and $f^*(q_1)$:
$$4q_1\frac{\partial^2 f^*}{\partial q_1^2} + (q_1+2)\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial q_1} + \frac{1}{2}f^* = 0.$$
I have checked that
$$f^* = c e^{-\frac{1}{4}q_1}$$
is a solution for any constant $c$.
Now comes the part I don't get. It says:

> Which conservation principle can be invoked to determine $c$? Check that the dimensional
> solution reads as
> $$u(x,t) = \frac{u_0}{\sqrt{4\pi\kappa t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4\kappa t}}.$$

I figure that the conservation principle must be the conservation of energy (heat) in the rod. What I don't understand is how to apply this to the dimensionless equation. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't your $q_2$ have length units? Or is this meant to be set up so $\delta$ has reciprocal length units, so that $\frac{u}{u_0}$ isn't dimensionless?

Comment: In any case the point is that in the dimensional equation you have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t) dx = u_0$ for all $t$. In the dimensionless form, you actually don't want to use $q_1$ as the independent variable. You really want $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\kappa t}}$ (i.e. $\operatorname{sign}(x) \sqrt{q_1}$) instead, since that's proportional to $x$ (and, in particular, takes on both signs, so the transformation even makes sense). With that as your independent variable you can integrate to get the dimensionless form of energy conservation.

Comment: Yes, the unit of $\delta$ is $\frac{1}{L}$, so that the unit of $u_0$ is $\frac{ML^3}{T^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Ian. I get it now.